# How to create action on Xcode action editor

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to try these new Xcode feature but I don't understand what to do.

I first create a new `SpriteKit action file`. Then action editor open with a text displayed in the middle of the screen: `No Preview Scene Selected`.

So how to "select Scene". Where to start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Looks like there is an Xcode 8 bug.  I get the same error you did trying to set the background scene using 8.1.  I'll file a radar ticket with Apple

[image: Xcode 8.1 bug]

It used to work ...

Use the dropdown menu below the scene (and above the timeline.)  I usually use GameScene.sks as the background to see my actions in the game world.

[See screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKhUU.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Xcode 8. Using the default template for a SpriteKit 'game', and its Actions.sks file.

Comment: Nothing happens. No matter what scene I select.

Comment: There is a layout / Animate toggle button above the time line.  You must have layout selected to make changes to the time line.

Comment: Using the default template for a SpriteKit 'game', and its Actions.sks file, in Xcode 12, it still does not work. The drop down box to select the scene is greyed out.

Comment: The same problem in Xcode 12.5.1. In the drop down list, GameScene.sks is grey and unselectable. Will report bug to Apple.

Comment: I have the same issue. Xcode 13.2 . is there a bug id on this or is it just me not understanding how to preview a scene in the action editor?